# Recursive cte with values from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I need some help with this please.

I would like to create a recursive query with values from a table for the anchor, multiplied by a coefficient from another table.

Let me be more explicit :

**Tables structure and filling :**

```
create table T
(
  Site varchar(10) primary key,
  Price money,
  Year int
);

create table B
( Site varchar(10),
  Coeff float,
  Year int
);

insert into T values /* Each Site appears only once here */
('A', 125.10, 2003),
('B', 78.10, 2002),
('C', 23.34, 2001)

insert into B values /* Each (Site,Year) appears only once here */
('A', 12, 2003),
('A', 0.111, 2004),
('B', 0.322, 2002),
('B', 0.333, 2003),
('C', 0.555, 2001),
('C', 0.666, 2002)
```

**My recursive formula is :**
 Price (n) = Price (n-1)* Coeff(n-1)
*(where n is the year)*

**Here is my last attempt :**

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT T.Site, T.Year, T.Price as RootPrice FROM T
UNION ALL 
SELECT T.Site, T.Year, CAST(cte.RootPrice * B.Coeff AS MONEY) AS PriceYear

FROM T INNER JOIN cte ON T.Site = cte.Site AND T.Year = cte.Year INNER JOIN B ON cte.Year = B.Year AND cte.Site = B.Site)    
SELECT * FROM cte
```

This cte is running endlessly. What am I missing ?

**Edit :**

**Output needed :**

```
Site  | Price     | Year 
---------------------------
 A    | 1501.2   | 2003
 A    | 166.78   | 2004
 B    | 25.15    | 2002
 B    | 8.37     | 2003
 C    | 12.95    | 2001
 C    | 8.63     | 2002
```

Comment: What is the output you need. Give Tabular format.

Comment: Output needed added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces the output you want:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Site = T.Site,
        Year = T.Year,
        Price = CONVERT(MONEY, T.Price * B.Coeff)
    FROM
        T AS T
        INNER JOIN B AS B ON 
            T.Site = B.Site AND
            T.Year = B.Year

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Site = C.Site,
        Year = C.Year + 1,
        Price = CONVERT(MONEY, C.Price * B.Coeff)
    FROM
        CTE AS C
        INNER JOIN B AS B ON 
            C.Site = B.Site AND
            C.Year + 1 = B.Year
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE AS C
ORDER BY
    C.Site,
    C.Year
```

The problem with your solution is that the anchor doesn't start with the correct price, you should multiply the price with coeff on the anchor. Keep in mind that the anchor is the first set of the resulting CTE and it is included in it.

So your anchor:

```
SELECT 
    T.Site, 
    T.Year, 
    T.Price as RootPrice 
FROM 
    T
```

Should start with the correct price for that year:

```
SELECT
    Site = T.Site,
    Year = T.Year,
    Price = CONVERT(MONEY, T.Price * B.Coeff)
FROM
    T AS T
    INNER JOIN B AS B ON 
        T.Site = B.Site AND
        T.Year = B.Year
```

And remove the `T` reference on the recursive set, since you don't need it anymore.

---

If you also want to see the root prices, you can tamper a little with the recursive join expression:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Site = T.Site,
        Year = T.Year,
        Price = T.Price,
        IsRoot = 1
    FROM
        #T AS T


    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Site = C.Site,
        Year = CASE WHEN C.IsRoot = 1 THEN C.Year ELSE C.Year + 1 END,
        Price = CONVERT(MONEY, C.Price * B.Coeff),
        IsRoot = 0
    FROM
        CTE AS C
        INNER JOIN #B AS B ON C.Site = B.Site
    WHERE
        (C.IsRoot = 1 AND C.Year = B.Year) OR
        (C.IsRoot = 0 AND C.Year + 1 = B.Year)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE AS C
ORDER BY
    C.Site,
    C.Year,
    C.IsRoot DESC

/*
Results:

Site       Year        Price                 IsRoot
---------- ----------- --------------------- -----------
A          2003        125,10                1
A          2003        1501,20               0
A          2004        166,6332              0
B          2002        78,10                 1
B          2002        25,1482               0
B          2003        8,3744                0
C          2001        23,34                 1
C          2001        12,9537               0
C          2002        8,6272                0

*/
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation.